# What is c# alternative of splice in c++

Tags: c#, c++

I have a c++ code and trying to write in C#

I couldn't figure out best alternative to splice in c#

Also C++ has a 'find' too to work on map,which I want to implement in C# on dictionary

Comment: If [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/splice/) is the `splice` you are using ("…Transfers elements from x into the container, inserting them at position.…") the nearest thing seems to be [`List.InsertRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/884ee1fz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to me, maybe along with some Linq `Skip` and `Take`.

Answer (score 2):

In your C++ example, you show:

```
statement_tokens.splice(statement_tokens.begin(), tokens, tokens.begin(), next_sc);
```

From what I understand ([documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/splice/)), this overload takes an insert position, a list (of the same type), and the first (inclusive) and last (exclusive) indexes of a range to splice into the insert position, and then inserts this range into the original list.

**Update:** AND it removes the items from the other list. I just added that functionality.

If this is correct, then the following extension method should work:

**List Extension Method** *(check the end of this answer for other overloads of this method)*

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static void Splice<T>(this List<T> list, int insertAtIndex, List<T> items, 
        int first, int last)
    {
        if (items == null) return;
        insertAtIndex = Math.Min(list.Count, Math.Max(0, insertAtIndex));
        first = Math.Min(items.Count - 1, Math.Max(0, first));
        last = Math.Min(items.Count, Math.Max(1, last));
        if (first >= last) return;

        list.InsertRange(insertAtIndex, items.GetRange(first, last - first));            
        items.RemoveRange(first, last - first);
    }
}
```

**Update 2**: Now, it looks like you're missing another extension method for `std::find_if`, which returns the index of a list item in a specified range, based on a method that returns true if the item meets some condition. So let's add the following method to the **ListExtensions** class above:

```
public static int FindIf<T>(this List<T> list, int start, int end, Func<T, bool> method)
{
    if (method == null) return end;
    if (!list.Any(method)) return end;
    start = Math.Min(list.Count - 1, Math.Max(0, start));
    end = Math.Min(list.Count, Math.Max(1, end));
    if (start >= end) return end;
    var range = list.GetRange(start, end - start);
    var index = range.IndexOf(list.First(method));
    if (index < start) return end;
    return index;
}
```

Notice that one of the arguments to this method is a function that takes an item of type `T` and returns a bool. This will be a simple method that checks if the string value of our token is a semicolon:

```
static bool TokenIsSemicolon(EvlToken token)
{
    return (token != null && token.Str == ";");
}
```

Now, you may notice that I referenced `token.Str`. This is from the `EvlToken` class, which was created to mimic the `C++ struct`:

```
class EvlToken
{
    public enum TokenType { Name, Number, Single }
    public TokenType Type { get; set; }
    public string Str { get; set; }
    public int LineNo { get; set; }
}
```

Now we can finish the conversion of the original method, calling our `FindIf` and `Splice` extension methods:

```
static bool MoveTokensToStatement(List<EvlToken> statementTokens, List<EvlToken> tokens)
{
    if (statementTokens == null || statementTokens.Count > 0) return false;
    if (tokens == null || tokens.Count == 0) return false;

    int nextSemiColon = tokens.FindIf(0, tokens.Count, TokenIsSemicolon);

    if (nextSemiColon == tokens.Count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Looked for ';' but reached the end of the file.");
        return false;
    }

    ++nextSemiColon;
    statementTokens.Splice(0, tokens, 0, nextSemiColon);
    return true;
}
```

**Additional Overloads**

For completeness, here is the extensions class with the other two overloads mentioned in the documentation:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Transfers all elements from 'items' into 'this' at the specified index
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of items in the list</typeparam>
    /// <param name="list">'this' instance</param>
    /// <param name="insertAtIndex">The index to insert the items</param>
    /// <param name="items">The list to transfer the items from</param>
    public static void Splice<T>(this List<T> list, int insertAtIndex,
        List<T> items)
    {
        if (items == null) return;
        list.Splice(insertAtIndex, items, 0, items.Count);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Transfers the element at 'itemIndex' from 'items' 
    /// into 'this' at the specified index
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of items in the list</typeparam>
    /// <param name="list">'this' instance</param>
    /// <param name="insertAtIndex">The index to insert the item</param>
    /// <param name="items">The list to transfer the item from</param>
    /// <param name="itemIndex">The index of the item to transfer</param>
    public static void Splice<T>(this List<T> list, int insertAtIndex,
        List<T> items, int itemIndex)
    {
        list.Splice(insertAtIndex, items, itemIndex, itemIndex + 1);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Transfers the specified range of elements from 'items' 
    /// into 'this' at the specified index
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of items in the list</typeparam>
    /// <param name="list">'this' instance</param>
    /// <param name="insertAtIndex">The index to insert the item</param>
    /// <param name="items">The list to transfer the item from</param>
    /// <param name="first">The index of the first item in the range</param>
    /// <param name="last">The exclusive index of the last item in the range</param>
    public static void Splice<T>(this List<T> list, int insertAtIndex, List<T> items, 
        int first, int last)
    {
        if (items == null) return;
        insertAtIndex = Math.Min(list.Count, Math.Max(0, insertAtIndex));
        first = Math.Min(items.Count - 1, Math.Max(0, first));
        last = Math.Min(items.Count, Math.Max(1, last));
        if (first >= last) return;

        list.InsertRange(insertAtIndex, items.GetRange(first, last - first));            
        items.RemoveRange(first, last - first);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Searches for the first item in the specified range that "method" returns true for
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of items in the list</typeparam>
    /// <param name="list">'this' instance</param>
    /// <param name="start">The index of the first item in the range</param>
    /// <param name="end">The exclusive index of the last item in the range</param>
    /// <param name="method">A method which takes type 'T' and returns a bool</param>
    /// <returns>The index of the item, if found, otherwise 'end'</returns>
    public static int FindIf<T>(this List<T> list, int start, int end, Func<T, bool> method)
    {
        if (method == null) return end;
        if (!list.Any(method)) return end;
        start = Math.Min(list.Count - 1, Math.Max(0, start));
        end = Math.Min(list.Count, Math.Max(1, end));
        if (start >= end) return end;
        var range = list.GetRange(start, end - start);
        var index = range.IndexOf(list.First(method));
        if (index < start) return end;
        return index;
    }
}
```

**Example Usage**

Here's an example using a list of `EvlTokens`, and then calling `MoveTokensToStatement` twice:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var tokens = new List<EvlToken>
    {
        new EvlToken {LineNo = 3, Str = "int", Type = EvlToken.TokenType.Single},
        new EvlToken {LineNo = 3, Str = "x", Type = EvlToken.TokenType.Name},
        new EvlToken {LineNo = 3, Str = "=", Type = EvlToken.TokenType.Single},
        new EvlToken {LineNo = 3, Str = "1", Type = EvlToken.TokenType.Number},
        new EvlToken {LineNo = 3, Str = "+", Type = EvlToken.TokenType.Single},
        new EvlToken {LineNo = 3, Str = "5", Type = EvlToken.TokenType.Number},
        new EvlToken {LineNo = 3, Str = ";", Type = EvlToken.TokenType.Single},
        new EvlToken {LineNo = 4, Str = "Console", Type = EvlToken.TokenType.Single},
        new EvlToken {LineNo = 4, Str = ".", Type = EvlToken.TokenType.Single},
        new EvlToken {LineNo = 4, Str = "WriteLine", Type = EvlToken.TokenType.Single},
        new EvlToken {LineNo = 4, Str = "(", Type = EvlToken.TokenType.Single},
        new EvlToken {LineNo = 4, Str = "Hello World", Type = EvlToken.TokenType.Single},
        new EvlToken {LineNo = 4, Str = ")", Type = EvlToken.TokenType.Single},
        new EvlToken {LineNo = 4, Str = ";", Type = EvlToken.TokenType.Single}
    };

    var statementTokens = new List<EvlToken>();

    MoveTokensToStatement(statementTokens, tokens);

    Console.WriteLine("Here is the result of calling 'MoveTokensToStatement' the first time:");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", statementTokens.Select(t => t.Str)));
    statementTokens.Clear();

    MoveTokensToStatement(statementTokens, tokens);

    Console.WriteLine("\nHere is the result of calling 'MoveTokensToStatement' the second time:");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", statementTokens.Select(t => t.Str)));
    statementTokens.Clear();


    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I added class Evl_token to code shown here. Plus I have added extra code too to show which approach I am trying to follow. Your Splice function takes int List as input not type of list I have defined in my code. also couldn't figure out how to use your splice on list I have defined.

Comment: No, my splice methods are generic - they take ANY type (which is represented in the code by `T`). I just used a `List<int>` as an example. What part are you not able to figure out?

Comment: In your code, the "splice" line should read: `statement_tokens.Splice(0, tokens, 0, next_sc);` But there may be problems before you get to this point?

Comment: I updated my answer with another extension method for `FindIf`, and how I would re-write the method you've been working on. Hope it helps clarify (and I hope it works as expected!).

Comment: Splice didn't work on statement_tokens and Findif didn't work on tokens. There isn't a way that we don't have to define find if or splice and use whatever is available in c# already? like find insert range or whatever is there. In ListExtensions I had to remove this otherwise splice function in it, asks for some super-class something.

Comment: You don't have to create extension methods, but they simplify things greatly. You can create "regular" methods instead, just do some additional error checking for the `this` object. But there is nothing built in that will remove items from one list and put them in another. How did it not work? Please be more specific, rather than *"some super-class something"* What was the specific error message?

Comment: you define listextensions class twice in your code,could figure out why?

Comment: The first one was to show the specific implementation that you needed, without the clutter of all the other overloads. The last one is the complete class.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of how to use the extension methods with the `EvlToken` class. Hopefully you can figure out the rest, cause I think the work is all done now... :)

Comment: if this is there like u have implemented there comes a red line under splice word and once i move cursor on it message comes,"extension methods must be defined in a top level static class,Listextensions is a nested class."

Comment: That means the class cannot live inside another class. It should be something like: `namespace MyNamespace { public static class ListExtensions {...} class EvlToken {...} class Program { static bool TokenIsSemicolon(...){...} static bool MoveTokensToStatement(...){...} private static void Main(){...} }`

Comment: u have done tokens.findif its not working,then u hav done statements_tokes.splice that is not working either.list evl_token doesnt contain findif and splice these are r error messages

Comment: yes once i moved that class out of program class that error is no longer there.but red line comes under splice and findif if i apply those on tokens list or statement_tokens list.like u implemented

Comment: Read the message that you see when you hover over the red line, and try to fix whatever it says is broken. I cannot see your code, but it works fine for me. Do you have `MoveTokensToStatement` inside the `Program` class as I showed in the comment above?

Comment: list <Evl_token>doesnt contain a definition for find if.seems like u hav done some change in class evl_token to make it work.

Comment: Nope, I gave you all the code I used. The error is referring to `List`, not `Evl_token`. Where did you put the `ListExtensions` class? That's the class that is extending the `List` class with new functionality.

Comment: now i dont see red line,i forgot to rewrite this word.thanks.i hope code works now

Comment: Can u remove statementTokens.Clear(); in ur main and run program? line int x...will come after line Console....... In splice of c++ int x... will come before Console......How can we modify class to achieve it?Also  statementTokens.Splice(statementTokens.First(), tokens, tokens.First(), nextSemiColon); didn't work on pattern of C++.

Comment: `statementTokens.First()` returns the first item from the list. `Splice` requires an `int` index, not an item from the list, for the first and third arguments; surely the compiler is telling you that. This is the reason in my call to `Splice` I pass `0`, to insert in the beginning. If you want to remove the `Clear` and have items added to the end of the list, then pass `statementTokens.Count` as the first parameter, which will insert at the end of the `statementTokens` list. Of course, if you do that repeatedly, you will just end up with a copy of `tokens`.

Comment: Yes I understand y u passed 0. I have seen in C++ two things findif and splice, both taking tokens.begin as arguments,but in C# whether its splice and findif created by u or there r built in commands like find,addrange and insertrange etc.they never take anything other than ints like 0.I just want to know how is it possible that v can use terms like tokens.first in c# instead of 0 to point to beginning of a list.

Comment: I don't know c++, what is the difference between tokens.begin and 0? Or tokens.end and array.length?

Comment: I have edited my question to show how without use of int we use for-each loop for c# and iterators in c++,to give an idea.the find if and splice of c++ r using concept used in iterators.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use the enumerator, which you can pass by using `statementTokens.GetEnumerator()`, which can be used to iterate over the list with `.Current` and `.Next`. I still have no idea why you want to do this, or which part of the solution here isn't working. Can you post a sample of the code you want to write that doesn't work with my solution? Also, I just fixed a bug in the `FindIf` method, because it wasn't actually limiting it's search to the specified range.

Comment: Can u check if i followed right approach to implement find for map in c++ to implement  in c# with FirstorDefault on Dictionary. map is like a dictionary in c++.Thanks

Comment: Couldnt figure out how to implement GetEnumerator(),Current and Next like u mentioned on Splice and findif u have implemented. Can u change code and show how to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@RufusL shows you how to write a method with the same postcondition, but doesn't really discuss any other characteristics of the algorithm.  In particular, his algorithm has higher complexity than the C++ splice.

Namely, splice on a *doubly linked list* such as C++'s `std::list` is an **O(1)** operation, because it only requires a constant number of pointer swaps.

.NET does have a doubly linked list class in the base library, which is `System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList`, but it keeps pointers back to the list from each node (`System.Collections.Generic.LinkedListNode`, `List` property) and each list stores a count.  As a result, in addition to the constant number of swaps of the forward and back pointers, **O(n)** node-to-list pointer updates will be required, and **O(n)** "distance" calculation is required in order to update the `Count` field on both lists.

So in order to achieve a true equivalent (**O(1)**) to C++ `std::list::splice`, one has to abandon the BCL `LinkedList` class and make a custom doubly linked list, with neither a cached `Count` field (LINQ `Count()` that walks the list will still work) nor pointers from list nodes to the list.